# How to revert the state of a button when clicked in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Am trying to revert the color and icon of a button when clicked, but I can't seem to come up with a good approach to deal with the state
The the color and icon only change one time but can't seem to revert back to the original once clicked again
I just want to be able to switch the color and icon back and forth on every click

Here's what I've tried so far...

[code in vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSShW.png)

Comment: You should add code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your function is setting the icon to a tick and the color to green. Every time you click it it will set it to the same value. I would remove both of this states and put only one - boolean value that checks the state of the button. If it is true, the icon should be a tick and color should be green. If it is false - cross and red.

```
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)

return (
  <main>
    <section 
      className={isClicked ? 'green' : 'red'}
      onClick={() => setIsClicked(!isClicked)}          
      >
        {isClicked ? *tick* : *cross*}
      </section>
  </main>
)
```

Comment: Beautiful solution u have right there...

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Here's a similar solution I just came up with

function App() {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

    const symbol = () => {
        setIsOpen(s => !s);
    }

    return (
        <>
            {
                isOpen ?
                    <main>
                        <section className="red" onClick={symbol}>✖</section>
                    </main>

                    : <main>
                        <section className="green" onClick={symbol}>✔</section>
                    </main>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Great! I have a small remark though. I would remove "main" tag and made it a parent. In this case isOpen will render only section part. Because if in the future you would like to have more content, you will have to insert it in both "main" tags, which brings to repetition.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).